# End line "\n" in FBJS Dialog

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I'm trying to show a FBJS Dialog with a multiline message.

```
message += "Please enter the name of the Post.\n"
message += "Please enter content.\n"
message += "Content must have at least 10 characters.";

new Dialog().showMessage("Error", message);
```

But that piece of code shows the message in the same line.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Thanks.
Ernesto Carrión

Comment: Just a guess, but try `<br>` instead of '\n'

Comment: Already tried but didn't work, but thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an fb:js-string when you have something other than text to show in a dialog.

Here's an example:

```
<fb:js-string var="messageToShow">
  Here's some text.<br />
  and some more text...<br />
  <p>You can even have HTML or FBML tags in here!</p>
  <img src="http://absolute.path.to/the/image.jpg" />
  <form id="selectFriendForm">
    <label class="RedLabel">Select a friend:</label>
    <fb:friend-selector name="uid" idname="selected_friend" />
  </form>
</fb:js-string>
```

And then you have the function that shows the dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showDialog() {
    var dialog = new Dialog(Dialog.DIALOG_POP);
        dialog.showChoice('Select a friend',
        messageToShow, // fb:js-string var name
        button_confirm = 'Choose this friend',
        button_cancel = 'Cancel'
      );

    dialog.onconfirm = function() {
      var formData = document.getElementById('selectFriendForm').serialize();
      // ajax call to save my selected friend or whatever
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The thing is that i don't know what the message should contain, so I need to build the message in execution time, and I that's what i don't know how is done.

Comment: just put a <div id="variableMessageContent"></div> inside the <fb:js-string> tag, and then you dynamically put the content you need using document.getElementById('variableMessageContent').setInnerFBML("my dynamic message"); on execution time